# simple server with multiple clients

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I'm trying to implement simple server with multiple clients. It should receive data from necessary socket, process and then send data to other clients. I use select module from Python standard library. 
Here's server:

```
class ProcessingServer:
    def __init__(self, bindaddress="localhost", portname=50001, maxqueue=5):
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((bindaddress, portname))
        self.socket.listen(maxqueue)
        self.inputsocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.data = ""

    def connect_to_output(self, address, port):
        self.inputsocket.connect((address, port))

    def start(self):
        rsocks = []
        wsocks = []
        rsocks.append(self.socket)
        wsocks.append(self.inputsocket)
        self.socket.accept()

        while True:
            try:
                reads, writes, errs = select.select(rsocks, wsocks, [])
            except:
                return
            for sock in reads:
                if sock == self.socket:
                    client, address  = sock.accept()
                    rsocks.append(client)
                else:
                    self.socket.send(self.data)
                    rsocks.remove(sock) 
            for sock in writes:
               if sock == self.inputsocket:
                    self.data = sock.recv(512)
                    wsocks.remove(sock)
                    print repr(self.data)
```

Here's simple client:

```
import socket
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysocket.connect(("localhost", 50001))
while True:
    data = mysocket.recv(512)
    print repr(data)
mysocket.close()
```

Receiving part of server works fine, but server doesn't produce any output. 
I'm not experienced in network programming at all and It feels like I'm missing something.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to keep things as simple as possible))

Comment: Twisted is far more simple than using sockets. You don't even have to worry about threads. Twisted does __all__ that jazz for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that seem odd in your script.

The standard usage of the select module is the following: you have one socket to listen to connections, and one socket per connection with the clients.

At first, only this socket is added to your potential readers list and your potential writers list is empty.

Calling select.select(potential_readers, potential_writers, potential_errors) will return 3 lists:
 - Sockets ready for reading
 - Sockets ready for writing
 - Sockets in error

In the list of sockets ready for reading, if the socket is the one listening for the connection, it must accept it and put the new socket in the potential reads, potential writes and potential errors.

If the socket is another one then, there is data to read from this socket. You shoud make a call to sock.recv(length)

If you want to send data, you should send it from your wlist returned by select.select.

The errlist is not used very often.

---

Now, for the solution for your problem, the way you describe your protocol (if I understood well), it might look like this:

```
import socket, select

sock_producer = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock_producer.bind(('localhost', 5000))
sock_producer.listen(5)
producers = []    

clients = []
sock_consumer_listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# Note: different port to differentiate the clients who receive data from the one who sends messages
sock_consumer_listener.bind(('localhost', 5001))

rlist = [sock_producer, sock_listener]
wlist = []
errlist = []

out_buffer = []

while True:
    r, w, err = select.select(rlist, wlist, errlist)
    for sock in r:
        if sock == sock_producer:
            prod, addr = sock.accept()
            producers.append(prod)
            rlist.append(prod)
         elif sock == sock_consumer_listener:
            cons, addr = sock.accept()
            clients.append(cons)
            wlist.append(cons)
         else:
            out_buffer.append(sock.recv(1024))

     out_string = ''.join(out_buffer)
     out_buffer = []

     for sock in w:
         if sock in clients:
             sock.send(out_string)
```

I haven't tested this code so there might be a few errors, but this is close to how I would do it.

Comment: +1 for  _"different port to differentiate the clients who receive data from the one who sends messages "_ Yes. One day , I passed several hours before understanding that. It isn't well underligned in docs and tutorials

Comment: @Martin: I don't get it. I have one socket - the source of data. The source socket is a client socket and I try to connect to it as soon as I start my server. (inputsocket in my example). Another socket is listening socket for incoming connections. But there are two "server" sockets in your example - sock_producer, sock_listener. Could you explain a little more?

Comment: @qutron: The source of data is one socket. In my case, the source socket is the producer. I listen instead of connecting somewhere, but it should be easy to adapt (Connect instead of listening) and remove the block `if sock == sock_producer: ...`

Comment: @Martin: Well, everything is fine now. Works like charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yeah...use [zeromq](http://zeromq.org) instead:

*server.py*

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REP)
socket.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:50001")

while True:
    msg = socket.recv()
    print "Got", msg
    socket.send(msg)
```

*client.py*

```
import zmq
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.REQ)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:50001")

for i in range(100):
    msg = "msg %s" % i
    socket.send(msg)
    print "Sending", msg
    msg_in = socket.recv()
```

Comment: is it safe to put zeromq onto the public internet yet?  as of earlier this year it was not, as malicious parties could trivial cause your listener to crash by senfing it malformed data.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to? Link? I would imagine it's going to be more stable than trying to do low-level socket stuff by hand. If you want something more robust, twisted might be the way to go.

Comment: For example, <http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-September/005944.html>.  The two issues mentioned there appear to be fixed (sadly the links are broken, so that's not entirely obvious).  I found that post with just a minute or two of googling.  Further searches may turn up other similar issues.

Comment: Difficult to deduce where zeromq stands in terms of stability. In my use I've not had any issues with it whatsoever, but I'm not building internet-facing services with it. Might be good to bring up your particular use-case in the IRC channel, or on the mailing list. It has no built-in security so it's not ideal for an internet-facing service by itself. Using twisted would be a better idea, if that's what you are building.

Comment: Does this zmq example work for basically one running client script on one and only one client ip+port. Meaning if you have a satellite office with 10 nodes (PCs) connecting through one IP address each node will need it's own port? Wouldn't running this script in different windows on the same machine be misleading? How will the server know which console window to send data too?